# C# tree drawing homework

Tags: c#, graph, bitmap, tree, drawing

I have a graph, it's input is like this:

7
1|2
1|3
2|4
2|5
5|7
3|6
5|7

The first number is a number of nodes and for example 1|2 means that there is edge from 1 to 2. The node can have only two children. I need to draw it on bitmap. I wrote a recursive function for depth of tree, so I can divide the height of bitmap. But now I have a trouble with drawing this tree, I'm not able to write function for drawing it.
Please advice a way to solve it. Thanks

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)    
            {  
                    odkud = graf[i, 0];  
                    kam = graf[i, 1];  
                    najdiPotomka2(i, kam, vyska);  
            }
                return maxVyska;
```

This is in function and that's how I get the depth, the recursive function is:

```
private Boolean najdiPotomka2(int stupen, int hodnota, int vyska)  
        {  
            vyska++;  
            int tempHodnota = hodnota;  
            for (int i = stupen + 1; i < pocetRadek; i++)  
            {  
                if (graf[i, 0] == tempHodnota)  
                {   
                    if(najdiPotomka2(i, graf[i,1], vyska))  
                    {   
                        vyska++;  
                        if (vyska > maxVyska) maxVyska = vyska;  
                        if ((i + 1) <= pocetRadek) najdiPotomka2(i, graf[i + 1, 1], vyska - 1);  
                        return true;  
                    }  
                    else  
                    {  
                        najdiPotomka2(i, tempHodnota, vyska-1);  
                        return true;  
                    }  
                }  
            }            
            if (vyska > maxVyska) maxVyska = vyska;  
            return false;  
        }
```

Now I am making steps and trying to find out if I can implement drawing straight to this recursive func. Also I've tried to implement tree structure from this website: http://www.slideshare.net/TelerikAcademy/21-trees-and-graphs-c-fundamentals but I got errors "constructor cannot call itself", but that's other problem.

Comment: From the rule, I think the first number is not necessary unless you use `Array` which needs some fixed init size. In this case it's the same as the number of actual lines for input. Also BTW, this looks like some homework.

Comment: regarding the advice to solve it, here's mine: what did you try? can you be more specific about "I'm not able to write function for drawing it"?

Comment: My apology, it is homework, forgot to write. I've tried to write recursive function to draw it. And do you think it's possible to draw it when I use array? The main think I don't know is, if I should use some structure (array, or what), or I can draw it as it is with some recursive function (which I tried, but unsuccessfully)

Comment: Your code is using an Array, while the link you gave is using Classes and Object Oriented Programming.  Which does your homework require?...they are **very** different implementations.

Comment: I can choose what I want. I thought it would be great to transform it to Objects.

Comment: I wrote an algorithm to draw binary trees a long time ago.  It was in Java, though.  I'll see if I can dig it up and post some generic pseudocode for you.